# Scala Cannot Resolve Symbol

Tags: scala, list, mapping

Currently my system has the ability for a user to enter 2 numbers, the last number on the tail is found and returned, how can I get the data and data2 to only show there numbers, not the SK1/SK3 before. Currently I am getting the error ;

Error:(177, 28) value >= is not a member of (String, Int)
    val highest = if (data >= data2){

```
 //Compare 2 values
  def mnuCompareTwoStocks(f: (String) => (String, Int)) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = f(readLine)
    print("Stock 2 > ")
    val data2 = f(readLine)
    val highest = if (data >= data2){
      println(data)
    }
    else
    {
      println(data2)
    }
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2} ${data2._1}: ${data2._2}")

  }
```

EDIT:
The working outcome

```
 //Compare 2 values
  def mnuCompareTwoStocks(f: (String) => (String, Int)) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = f(readLine)
    print("Stock 2 > ")
    val data2 = f(readLine)
    if (data._2 >= data2._2){
      println("The higher stock is " + data)
    }
    else
    {
      println("The higher stock is " + data2)
    }
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2} ${data2._1}: ${data2._2}")

  }
```

Comment: Make it `val highest = if (...) data else data2`

Comment: @rethab same error is occuring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare 2 tuples of type `(String,Int)`. There is no simple comparison operator for such.

```
scala> ("a",3) > ("b",0)
<console>:12: error: value > is not a member of (String, Int)
       ("a",3) > ("b",0)
               ^
```

Do you want the `String` to take precedence or the `Int`?

```
scala> ("a",3)._1 > ("b",0)._1
res0: Boolean = false

scala> ("a",3)._2 > ("b",0)._2
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Yes, I want int as I can compare them, I have edited my question and the error

Comment: If you want the `Int` for comparison then extract it as shown.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code which are causing the errors you're seeing.

First, you have a syntax error: to print out the variable *highest* the way you want to, you need to use `+` for string concatenation: `println("The higher stock is " + highest)`

Secondly, *highest* is only declared inside your `if` statements so it's out of scope for the `println` statement. You can solve this issue by declaring it in scope:

```
...
var highest = 0.0
if(...){
    highest = ...
}
else {
    highest = ...
}
println("The higher stock is " + highest)
```

Lastly, and most importantly, the overall design of your method doesn't really make sense to me. *f* is your parameter to *mnuCompareTwoStocks*, and it's a **function** that converts from String to (String, Int). So why are you calling *apply* (via `f(readLine)`) on this function and seemingly expecting a numeric datatype back? What is even the purpose of this parameter? If, indeed, you do want the tuple to be returned, you'll need to unpack the numeric component before comparing the values:

```
val data = f(readLine)
val data2 = f(readLine)
if (data._2 >= data2._2)
...
```

I see you edited your question to solve the first two issues. However, now you're pointlessly setting `val highest = Unit` with your if statement...

Regardless, you should unpack the Int component of your tuple if you want to do numeric comparison between them, as shown above.